# Array: Filter with preg_replace and Sorting [PHP - WordPress]

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have a list of categories that are made up of multiple recurring (italian) words, like this:

- racconti sulla vita
- racconti di passione
- racconti sui pensieri
- racconti motivazionali
- ...

What I need to do is remove from the list all the recurring words (racconti, sulla, di, sui, sul, etc.) and then order the rest from A to Z.

The result is really weird: the total number of categories is 42 and I get the first 31 results in the right order (in this case from B to V). From 32nd item, the list starts again in the right order (from A to S).

It's like if the list was split in 2 parts.

This is my code:

```
$terms_tipologia = get_terms( 'tipologia', array( 'hide_empty' => true ) );

foreach ( $terms_tipologia as $tipologia ) :

    $words = array("racconti", "sul", "sull'", "sulla", "sulle", "sullo", "sui", "di");
    $pattern = '/\b(?:' . join('|', $words) . ')\b/i';

    $term_name = preg_replace($pattern, '', $tipologia->name);
    $term_link = get_term_link($tipologia);

    $reorder[$term_link] = $term_name;

endforeach;

asort($reorder);

foreach ( $reorder as $link => $nome ) :

    echo '<li><a href="'.esc_url( $link ).'">' . $nome . '</a></li>';

endforeach;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think your issue come from space before/after removed word.

here sample than should work :

```
$terms_tipologia = [
    'racconti sulla vita',
    'racconti di passione',
    'sulle amotivazionali',
     'boem sulle ',
    'racconti sui pensieri',
    'racconti motivazionali'
];

$words = ["racconti", "sul", "sull'", "sulla", "sulle", "sullo", "sui", "di"];
//You should not rebuild on each loop iteration your pattern, i have also add optional space on regex.
$pattern = '/\b\s*(?:' . join('|', $words) . ')\s*\b/i';
$reorder = [];
foreach ( $terms_tipologia as $tipologia ) {

    $term_name = preg_replace($pattern, '', $tipologia);
    $reorder[] = trim($term_name); // I remove useless space.
}

asort($reorder);

var_dump($reorder);
```

You can see online example : http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/21a4c4beb156e2a4904f4a913a9b60334496d2d7

Answer (score 0):

You will need to iterate over your array of WP Term objects and perform replacements on the `name` property values.  Your `foreach()` will not need to explicitly use `&` on the `$wpTerm` variable declaration in the `foreach()` because objects are referenced by default.  The replacement pattern should use word boundaries on either side of the non-capturing group and then zero or one whitespace after the matched word.  To mop up a remaining space at the end of the modified phrase (if the replaced word was the last word of the phrase), call `rtrim()`.

Save the "cleaned names" as a separate, flat array to make the sorting process simple.  Call `array_multisort()` with the clean array first and the WP objects array second.

After sorting, make one more loop over the object array to print what you desire.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/GILcF))

```
$tipologiaTerms = [
    (object) ['term_id' => 1, 'name' => 'racconti sulla vita', 'slug' => 'racconti-sulla-vita', 'taxonomy' => 'category'],
    (object) ['term_id' => 2, 'name' => 'racconti di passione', 'slug' => 'racconti-di-passione', 'taxonomy' => 'category'],
    (object) ['term_id' => 3, 'name' => 'sulle amotivazionali', 'slug' => 'sulle-amotivazionali', 'taxonomy' => 'category'],
    (object) ['term_id' => 4, 'name' => 'boem sulle', 'slug' => 'boem-sulle', 'taxonomy' => 'category'],
    (object) ['term_id' => 5, 'name' => 'racconti sui pensieri', 'slug' => 'racconti-sui-pensieri', 'taxonomy' => 'category'],
    (object) ['term_id' => 6, 'name' => 'racconti motivazionali', 'slug' => 'racconti-motivazionali', 'taxonomy' => 'category'],
];

$blacklist = ["racconti", "sul", "sull'", "sulla", "sulle", "sullo", "sui", "di"];
$pattern = '/\b(?:' . implode('|', $blacklist) . ')\b\s?/i';
$cleanNames = [];
foreach ($tipologiaTerms as $wpTerm) {
    $wpTerm->name = rtrim(preg_replace($pattern, '', $wpTerm->name));
    $cleanNames[] = $wpTerm->name;
}
array_multisort($cleanNames, $tipologiaTerms);

foreach ($tipologiaTerms as $wpTerm) {
    printf(
        '<li><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n",
        esc_url(get_term_link($wpTerm)),
        $wpTerm->name
    );
}
```